# SharePoint Column JSON formatting alignment

Tags: sharepoint-online, conditional, json-formatting, column-formatting, background

As mentioned in the Title I have some issues with trying to align my background color formatting as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

What I hope to do is to get the BACKGROUND COLOR to align WITHOUT causing the words to move upwards as shown in the 2nd screenshot below:

[image]

Below is the code that I am currently using:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$FlowStatus] == 'Expired', 'Expired', @currentField",
  "attributes": {},
  "style": {
    "display": "table-cell",
    "text-align": "center",
    "vertical-align": "middle",
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            "Approved"
          ]
        },
        "#ABDB77",
        {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$FlowStatus]",
                "Expired"
              ]
            },
            "#FF6347",
            {
              "operator": "?",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "@currentField",
                    "Pending"
                  ]
                },
                "#FFD700",
                {
                  "operator": "?",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField",
                        "Rejected"
                      ]
                    },
                    "#bcbcbc",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "customRowAction": {},
  "children": []
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Suggestions are welcomed too.

**UPDATE**
I've tried the updated code provided by one of the suggestions and below are the results.

[image]

It's close to my intended outcome now except the text's vertical alignment is still off (on top instead of middle)

**UPDATE 2:** 
Thanks to the suggestions, I had an idea which surprisingly worked. Below is the code and screenshot for those who might face the same issue. It's quite a long approach but it works.

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if([$FlowStatus] == 'Expired', 'Expired', @currentField",
    "attributes": {},
    "style": {
      "border-radius": "0em",
       "height": "0",
       "min-width": "0em",
       "color": "black",
       "text-align": "center",
       "position": "left",
       "top": "0",
       "right": "0em",
      "background-color": {
        "operator": "?",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "==",
            "operands": [
              "@currentField",
              "Approved"
            ]
          },
          "#ABDB77",
          {
            "operator": "?",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "==",
                "operands": [
                  "[$FlowStatus]",
                  "Expired"
                ]
              },
              "#FF6347",
              {
                "operator": "?",
                "operands": [
                  {
                    "operator": "==",
                    "operands": [
                      "@currentField",
                      "Pending"
                    ]
                  },
                  "#FFD700",
                  {
                    "operator": "?",
                    "operands": [
                      {
                        "operator": "==",
                        "operands": [
                          "@currentField",
                          "Rejected"
                        ]
                      },
                      "#bcbcbc",
                      ""
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "customRowAction": {},
    "children": []
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the current output of this JSON code? as shown in image 1 or image 2?

Comment: Apologies for the edit. I missed out 1 line in my code. The current code output is image 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `div` with full width then try adding `"width": "100%"` to the `style` attribute, like:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$FlowStatus] == 'Expired', 'Expired', @currentField",
  "attributes": {},
  "style": {
    "width": "100%",
    "display": "table-cell",
    "text-align": "center",
    "vertical-align": "middle",
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            "Approved"
          ]
        },
        "#ABDB77",
        {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$FlowStatus]",
                "Expired"
              ]
            },
            "#FF6347",
            {
              "operator": "?",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "@currentField",
                    "Pending"
                  ]
                },
                "#FFD700",
                {
                  "operator": "?",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField",
                        "Rejected"
                      ]
                    },
                    "#bcbcbc",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "customRowAction": {},
  "children": []
}
```

**Update**:

Also, you can try adding `padding` to your `div` by removing `display` attribute as given below:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if([$FlowStatus] == 'Expired', 'Expired', @currentField",
    "attributes": {},
    "style": {
      "padding": "0 25%",
      "display": "flex",
      "text-align": "center",
      "vertical-align": "middle",
      "background-color": {
        "operator": "?",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "==",
            "operands": [
              "@currentField",
              "Approved"
            ]
          },
          "#ABDB77",
          {
            "operator": "?",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "==",
                "operands": [
                  "[$FlowStatus]",
                  "Expired"
                ]
              },
              "#FF6347",
              {
                "operator": "?",
                "operands": [
                  {
                    "operator": "==",
                    "operands": [
                      "@currentField",
                      "Pending"
                    ]
                  },
                  "#FFD700",
                  {
                    "operator": "?",
                    "operands": [
                      {
                        "operator": "==",
                        "operands": [
                          "@currentField",
                          "Rejected"
                        ]
                      },
                      "#bcbcbc",
                      ""
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "customRowAction": {},
    "children": []
  }
```

Comment: I've tried adding "width": "100%", to the style attribute but it seems like there are no changes. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Can you add screenshot of how is it showing after adding width? If it is not working for you then try removing `display` attribute and adding `width` attribute.

Comment: It looks exactly the same as the first screenshot. Removing the display attribute while adding the width attribute will result in exactly the same output as screenshot 2.

Comment: Then you can add some `padding-top` or `top` to make you content in the middle.

Comment: Try updated code. This is working for me.

Comment: I've tried the update code. It's quite close to my intended outcome now. It's like screenshot 2 but the vertical-align of the text is still not in the middle but on top (see updated screenshot 3)

Comment: If you see at updated code, you will know that I have added some padding from left and right side. Similarly you can add some CSS to make it middle from top side.

Comment: Try adding `"display": "flex"` to your style.

Comment: Hi, Does this answers your question? If Yes, please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you have any doubt or issues you can ask it here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the bg color is not priority then you can use SharePoint's default class which is created to format column, check following link for default css class and JSON examples:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#style-guidelines

Following JSON I am using in my columns:

```
{ 
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",  "attributes": {
"class": "=if(@currentField == true, 'sp-field-severity--good', 'sp-field-severity--blocked') + ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"
},
"children": [
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
    "display": "inline-block",
    "padding": "0 4px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "=if(@currentField == true, 'CheckMark', 'ErrorBadge')"
  }
},
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "txtContent": "=if(@currentField == true, 'Yes', 'No')"
}
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately the bg color is important.